# Simple C syntax for subtracting from char type, lowercase

Tags: c, syntax, char, lowercase

I'm getting a seg. fault when I try to subtract 32 from a char type (trying to convert to lowercase without tolower() in C. I have done the prerequisite searching for relevant Q/A threads with no luck. I also tried 'a' - 'A' for the conversion value, '32', casting it as (char*) and anything else I could think of. For an example:

```
char* s1 = "Bob";

if (*s1 >= 97 && *s1 <= 122)
     *s1 -= 32;
}
```

Any advice?

Edit:

After following the help below, I still get the error. (For this example, I am only trying to change the first letter of the name to lowercase.) Here is what I am trying:

```
 char* s1 = "Bob";
 printf("\n %s before", s1);

 // below I call my string length function to get actual size instead of 100
 char* temp = malloc(100);   
 temp = s1;

 if (*temp >= 'A' && *temp <= 'Z'){
    *temp -= 32;
 }

 printf("\n%s after", temp);
 free(temp);
```

Also, why do I need to allocate memory for a string that already is in memory?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you're modifying a string literal, don't use "magic numbers". Don't write `97` and `122` when you mean `'a'` and `'z'`.

Comment: Ok, I thought C treated chars as their ASCII value if compared with numbers

Comment: It does. But you should use the actual characters so it's more readable.

Comment: @user2827214: It does, but Keith's point is that your code is more readable if you say `'a'` rather than `97`.

Comment: I guess that not everyone would agree but I prefer to write `s1[0]` instead of `*s1` to access the first element.

Comment: @jonhopkins: No, C does not treat characters as their ASCII values. Many C implementations do, but the C standard is specifically written to allow non-ASCII encodings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

```
char* s1 = "Bob";
```

A string literal creates a read-only array of `char`; this array is *static* meaning that it exists for the entire lifetime of your program. For historical reasons, it's not `const`, so the compiler won't necessarily warn you if you attempt to modify it, but you should carefully avoid doing so.

`s1` points to the first character of that array. You may not modify `*s1`. For safety, you should declare the pointer as `const`:

```
const char *s1 = "Bob";
```

If you want a modifiable character array, you can create it like this:

```
char s1[] = "Bob";
```

Now let's look at the remaining code:

```
if (*s1 >= 97 && *s1 <= 122)
     *s1 -= 32;
}
```

`97` and `122` are the numeric ASCII codes for `'a'` and `'z'`. `32` is the difference between a lower case letter and the corresponding upper case letter -- again, in ASCII.

The C language doesn't guarantee that characters are represented in ASCII, or in any of the character sets that are compatible with it. On an IBM mainframe, for example, characters are represented in EBCDIC, in which the codes for the letters are not contiguous (there are gaps), and the difference between corresponding lower case and upper case letters is 64, not 32.

EBCDIC systems are rare these days, but even so, portable code tends to be *clearer* than non-portable code, even aside from any practical issues of whether the code will work on all systems.

As I'm sure you know, the best way to do this is to use the `tolower` function:

```
*s1 = tolower((unsigned char)*s1);
```

Note the cast to `unsigned char`. The `to*()` and `is*()` functions declared in `<ctype.h>` are oddly behaved, for historical reasons. They don't work on `char` arguments; rather, they work on `int` arguments that are within the range of `unsigned char`. (They also accept `EOF`, which is typically `-1`). If plain `char` is signed, then passing a `char` value that happens to be negative causes undefined behavior. Yes, it's annoying.

But you say you don't want to use `tolower`. (Which is fine; learning to do things like this yourself is a good exercise.)

If you're willing to assume that upper case letters are contiguous, and that lower case letters are contiguous, then you can do something like this:

```
if (*s1 >= 'a' && *s1 <= 'z') {
    *s1 -= 'a' - 'A';
}
```

That's still not portable to non-ASCII systems, but it's a lot easier to read if you don't happen to have the ASCII table memorized.

It also makes it a little more obvious that you've got the logic backwards. You say you want to convert to lower case, but your code converts from lower case to upper case.

Or you can use a lookup table that maps lower case letters to upper case letters:

```
char to_lower[CHAR_MAX] = { 0 }; /* sets all elements to 0 */
to_lower['A'] = 'a';
to_lower['B'] = 'b';
/* ... */
to_lower['Z'] = 'z';
```

Or, if your compiler supports compound literals:

```
const char to_lower[CHAR_MAX] = {
    ['A'] = 'a',
    ['B'] = 'b',
    /* ... */
};
```

I'll leave it to you to fill in the rest write the code to use it.

And now you can see why the `tolower` and `toupper` functions exist -- so you don't have to deal with all this stuff (apart from the odd `unsigned char` casts you'll need).

**UPDATE :**

In response to the new parts of your question:

```
char* temp = malloc(100);   
temp = s1;
```

That assignment `temp = s1;` doesn't copy the allocated string; it just copies the *pointer*. `temp` points to 100 bytes of allocated space, but then you make `temp` point to the (read-only) string literal, and you've lost any references to the allocated space, creating a memory leak.

You can't *assign* strings or arrays in C. To copy a string, use the `strcpy()` function:

```
char *temp = malloc(100);
if (temp == NULL) {     /* Don't assume the allocation was successful! */
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
strcpy(temp, s1);
```

> Also, why do I need to allocate memory for a string that already is in memory?

It's in memory, but it's memory that you're not allowed to modify. If you want to modify it, you need to copy it to a modifiable location. Or, as I suggested above, you can put it in read/write memory in the first place:

```
char s[] = "Bob";
```

That initialization copies the string into the array `s`.

Comment: great explanation, I had no idea that you could not modify a char array when declared like I did.

Comment: Great explanation, especially *magic number* and *look-up table* part.

Comment: The problems in the code are sufficiently numerous that you might want to divide this answer into parts and label each part (as with the “##” or “###” mark-up).

Answer (score 7):

You can't alter literal strings like that - they are (usually) in read-only memory.  You need to make a writeable copy of the string literal:

```
char* name = "Bob";
char* s1 = strdup(name);

...

free(s1);  // And you also need this to avoid a memory leak!
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize char and use malloc to allocat memory to store all string and than use for loop and convert whole string in lower case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to

1. Allocate buffer
2. Copy string "Bob" to your buffer
3. Loop through the string, editing it as you go.

Answer (score 0):

This fails because string literals are usually stored in read-only memory.

The easiest fix is to use the literal to initialize an array, the array will be modifiable (unless explicitly made `const` so don't do that):

```
char s1[] = "Bob";
```

Also, it's very bad form to hardcode ASCII, use the `islower()` and `tolower()` functions from `<ctype.h>` to make this code proper.

Comment: the point of this is to not use the c-lib functions like islower() etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
char *s1 = "Bob";
```

is creating a pointer to a string constant. That means the string `"Bob"` will be somewhere in the read-only part of the memory and you just have a pointer to it. You can use the string as read-only. You **cannot** make changes to it.
Example:

```
s1[0] = 'b';
```

Is asking for trouble.

To make changes to `s1` you should allocate memory for it

```
s1 = malloc(10); //or what you want
```

Now changes to `s1` can be done easily.

Comment: And why 10? And what is that 14?

Comment: @Maxime; It depends on OP choice. He might take `4` or `40`. `10` is not bad.

Comment: @haccks you have edited your answer to remove the 14. Anyway, you should explain **why** it does not work instead of suggesting something different.